# Eliminar comportamiento por defecto de un select

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-select

Dentro de un form tengo varios elementos entre estos un select el dilema es que cuando yo recargo la pagina y cambio por primera vez el valor de ese select a otro valor la pagina baja a la siguiente sección, entonces me toca subir con la rueda del ratón y seguir llenando los datos pero es molesto que tal cual vez me esté bajando, estoy trabjando solo con HTML, CSS y Js todo vanilla, ¿alguien que por favor me colabore en como eliminar ese comportamiento por defecto?

```html
<form class="product-form">
  <label>Tamaño</label>
  <select id="tamano" onchange="changeDivision()">
    <option value="ninguno" selected="selected">--- Ninguno ----</option>
    <option value="porcion">Porción</option>
    <option value="personal">Personal (22Cm)</option>
    <option value="pequena">Pequeña (26Cm)</option>
    <option value="mediana">Mediana (31Cm)</option>
    <option value="grande">Grance (40Cm)</option>
    <option value="jumbo">Jumbo (50Cm)</option>
  </select>

  <label for="">División</label>
  <select id="porciones">
    <option value="noDisponible">--- No Disponible ----</option>
    <option value="estandar">Estandar Porcion</option>
    <option value="cuatro">4 Porciones</option>
    <option value="seis">6 Porciones</option>
    <option value="ocho">8 Porciones</option>
    <option value="diez">10 Porciones</option>
    <option value="doce">12 Porciones</option>
    <option value="dieciseis">16 Porciones</option>
  </select>

  <input type="submit" value="Hacer Pedido">
</form>
```

Comment: Creo que ese no es un comportamiento por defecto de un select. Algo debes tener en tus funciones para que "la pagina baje a la siguiente sección". Agrega el código `js` y el `css` mínimo para tratar de recrear el comportamiento que refieres.

Comment: A simplve vista, diría que tenes que sacar el `onchange` del `select`

Comment: es que no encontré otra forma de atrapar el evento cuando se escoge otra opción en un select, me tocó así

Comment: ya intentaste ponerle un action a tu form?